# Mercurial - clone - unknown command

Tags: macos, mercurial

I can't clone a repository:

```
$ hg clone​ https://some_url local_folder
hg: unknown command 'clone https://some_url​ local'
Mercurial Distributed SCM

$ type hg
hg is hashed (/usr/local/bin/hg)

$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.3)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It says, as you can see, `clone` is unknown command.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying `clone` is an unknown command. It's saying clone glommed together with a URL is.

Compare what you're getting:

```
hg: unknown command 'clone https://some_url​ local'
```

with an actual unknown command with an argument:

```
ry4an@four:~$ hg frozzle long_url_argument_here
hg: unknown command 'frozzle'
```

Notice how my long_url_argument_here doens't show up and definitely isn't in the single quotes in the error but yours is?

So the problem is in how you're invoking mercurial.  Either that space isn't a space or you're calling it from a shell script and you've used `$*` when you meant `"$@"` or you've got a bad alias or something.

Whatever's wrong it's in your shell not Mercurial.